# Change the Value Folder , string.xml file

Tags: android

I want to make a bi-language application. I have created two folders value-ar and value-en. I want to change the folder in a click of a button from value-ar to value-en . How can I change that ?

Comment: what do you mean change folder ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You just need to change the Locale of the device

Comment: It automatic take appropriate value from folder when you change your language from setting .

Comment: i can't thing it's possible to change folder name & i thing  your requirement also different.

Comment: Example : let's say the default language is the English language. If the user clicks on Lang. The values of the file string that is in the folder value-ar  will be used vice versa

Comment: For every page you will have to load language from shared prefs, make a change in the shared prefs on button click and load alternate resources. So the first thing you do when you load the page is to check the shared prefs variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the language programmatically but it is not recommended.

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale("en_us");
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

This would set the langauge to en (in your words, change the folder ^^)